# Invalid Procedure call on Union

Tags: excel, vba

I Keep getting invalid procedure call on the following union function. I am unsure what is wrong. Below also is how a given variable is defined (they are all pretty similar)

```
Union(v, ci, ri, oi, tai, rvp, rvd, cvp, cvd, cbdp, cbdd, egi, te, noi, facr, mbids, ecf, dscr, n).Copy
```

how varibles are defined

```
 Set ecf = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Excess Cash Flow", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If ecf Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set ecf = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
    End If
```

global variables

```
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
     Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
End Property
Property Get wSrc() As Workbook
Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
End Property
Property Get col() As Long
    col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="MBI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property
Property Get col2() As Long
    col2 = wSrc.Sheets("Inputs").Columns.Find(What:="Deal Team", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property

Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property
```

Comment: Would help to supply some context for the `Union` line.

Comment: You will get an error if all ranges aren't on the same worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your one `Union(...).Copy` line with:

```
Dim copyrange As Range
Set copyrange = v
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, ci)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, ri)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, oi)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, tai)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, rvp)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, rvd)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, cvp)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, cvd)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, cbdp)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, cbdd)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, egi)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, te)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, noi)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, facr)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, mbids)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, ecf)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, dscr)
Set copyrange = Union(copyrange, n)
copyrange.Copy
```

This will build the Union one range at a time, and will error on the line that has a problem. You can then investigate further.